# Allow docker to utilize the complete CPUs and underlying RAM

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, docker-machine, prisma

Is there a way to specify the total RAM and total CPUs that a docker can use? My machine's size is 16 GB RAM and 4 CPUs.

How can I make the docker-machine to utilize the complete RAM and underlying CPUs?

Here is `dockerfile`

```
version: '3'
services:
prisma:
    image: prismagraphql/prisma:1.34
    restart: always
    ports:
    - "4466:4466"
    environment:
    JAVA_OPTS: '-Xmx8192m'
    PRISMA_CONFIG: |
        port: 4466
        databases:
        default:
            connector: mongo
            uri: 'mongodb+srv://abc:test@abc.net/default_default?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
```

Comment: Docker can _always_ use all your CPU and RAM by default. It's not like a virtual machine where CPUs need to be emulated -- it's just a set of namespaces programs run in; unless you explicitly place limits on those namespaces they can use the full set of resources just like anything else.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking is the default behavior.

From [docs](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints)

> By default, a container has no resource constraints and can use as much of a given resource as the host’s kernel scheduler allows.

What you can do to ensure a container gets minimum amount of resources and is not at the mercy of scheduler is to use the resource `reservations` to ensure the container always has minimum required resources and optionally `limits` if you also want to enforce upper threshold for the resource usage.

See [Resources section in docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/)

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    deploy:
      resources:
        # upper threshold
        limits:
          cpus: '0.50'
          memory: 50M
        # lower threshold
        reservations:
          cpus: '0.25'
          memory: 20M
```

> In this general example, the Redis service is constrained to use no more than 50M of memory and 0.50 (50% of a single core) of available processing time (CPU), and has 20M of memory and 0.25 CPU time reserved (as always available to it).